# Seaborn Catplot only changing the X and Y labels on 1 of the rows

Tags: python, matplotlib, seaborn

I have created the following `catplot` with this code:

```
tkt_plot_detailed = sns.catplot(data=resolved_time_length, x='Time_to_resolve_days',y='Ticket_category',
       kind='box',row='Priority_level',height=4,aspect=3,
       orient="h",linewidth=2.5)
plt.xlabel('Days to Resolve', fontsize=15)
plt.ylabel('Ticket Category', fontsize=15)
plt.xlim(-1,30)
plt.show()
```

This produces this graph:
[image]

The problem that I have is that i have changed the x and y label texts and font sizes but this changes have only taken effect on the bottom row of the graph. How can I make the changed to all the rows of my graph please?

Comment: Use your object `tkt_plot_detailed` and apply methods such as `set_xlabel` and `set_ylabel`. Cheers.

Comment: @Irnzcig I have tried this: `tkt_plot_detailed.set_xlabel('TEST')` but that gives me this error: `AttributeError: 'FacetGrid' object has no attribute 'set_xlabel'`

Comment: You're right. Too long for a comment, I add a short answer.

Comment: This is an old post, but `tkt_plot_detailed.set_xlabels` works. **Note the plural "s" in labels**. You can check the available methods by `dir(tkt_plot_detailed)`

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Either of these two ways should work:

```
tkt_plot_detailed.set_xlabels('Days to Resolve', fontsize=15) # not set_label
tkt_plot_detailed.set_ylabels('Ticket Category', fontsize=15)
```

Or:

```
for ax in tkt_plot_detailed.axes.flatten():
    ax.xlabel('Days to Resolve', fontsize=15)
    ax.ylabel('Ticket Category', fontsize=15)
```

Comment: @irnczig trhe answer on your comment didnt work because the method was called set_xlabels instead of set_xlabel. it works now!, if you amend this answer i will mark it as correct otherwise i will just post the answer myself. Thanks for all your help!

Answer (score 1):

The accepted answers didn't work for me. But this code from the [docs](https://seaborn.pydata.org/generated/seaborn.catplot.html) worked:

```py
tkt_plot_detailed.set_axis_labels("Days to Resolve", "Ticket Category")
```